# Play 2.5 Deadbolt-2's @subjectPresentOr migrating from Java -> Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, deadbolt-2

I'm migrating an existing Java Play 2.5 application to Scala and found in the view `main.scala.html` the use of the following [deadbolt-2](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2) class [`subjectPresentOr`](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala/blob/master/code/app/be/objectify/deadbolt/scala/views/subjectPresentOr.scala.html):

```
@subjectPresentOr() {
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    @defining(userProvider.getUser(session())) { user =>
    ... user is present html
    }
} {
  ... user is NOT present html    
}
```

After migrating all controllers and actions to Scala (and changing the deadbolt-2 dependency from Java -> Scala) I get the following compiler error due to the fact that [`subjectPresentOr`](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala/blob/master/code/app/be/objectify/deadbolt/scala/views/subjectPresentOr.scala.html) requires an implicit request of type `AuthenticatedRequest[Any]`:

```
main.scala.html:49: could not find implicit value for parameter request: 
    be.objectify.deadbolt.scala.AuthenticatedRequest[Any]
```

and I have some intuition why ... some times e.g. when the user is not yet logged in there is no request of type deadbolt-2's `AuthenticatedRequest[_]` but the superclass type `play.api.mvc.RequestHeader` and it can't be rightfully so implicitly matched with its subclass `AuthenticatedRequest[_]`.

<s>The question is why this works in the Java version in the first place?</s> The Java version of [`@subjectPresentOr`](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java/blob/02db617a91e919ac41d96a368cb8dca8075e0740/code/app/be/objectify/deadbolt/java/views/dynamicOr.scala.html) doesn't require any implicit request :)

To fix it in the Scala version I would wrap the `@subjectPresentOr` block with pattern matching to discover the dynamic type of the implicit request and only if its dynamic type is `AuthenticatedRequest[_]` I will then show the block and pass to `@subjectPresentOr` explicitly the narrowed request of that type. This is not super elegant though but I can't figure any other way ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java version of Play has a `Http.Context` available to it via ThreadLocals, whereas the Scala version uses requests.  These may be implicit or explicit.

Looking at your controllers, when you add Deadbolt to an action you will receive an `AuthenticatedRequest`.  So, a non-Deadbolt action of

```
def foo = Action { request =>
  // request is of type Request
}
```

would receive a `request` of type `Request`, whereas the same action protected by Deadbolt

```
def foo = actionBuilder.SubjectPresentAction().defaultHandler() { request =>
  // request is of type AuthenticatedRequest
}
```

receives a `request` of type `AuthenticatedRequest`.

If you want to convert a `Request` to an `AuthenticatedRequest` because you're calling a template that contains Deadbolt constraints yet your controller action is unconstrained, you can use `WithAuthRequestAction`:

```
def foo = actionBuilder.WithAuthRequestAction().defaultHandler() { request =>
  // request is of type AuthenticatedRequest
}
```

If you're injecting `DeadboltActions` in place of `ActionBuilders`, the same holds true:

```
def foo= deadboltActions.SubjectPresent()() { request =>
  // request is of type AuthenticatedRequest
}
```

You can also just create an instance of `AuthenticatedRequest` from the existing `Request` and with no `Subject` by using `new AuthenticatedRequest(request, None)`.

Comment: @(Steve Chalonder) Thank you, yes it all makes sense. I think the problem is solved using `actionBuilder.WithAuthRequestAction().defaultHandler()` in every action that returns `RequestHeader`. btw is this a shorter version: `actionBuilder.WithAuthRequestAction()()` ? again thank you for the help and for the very clean code of Deadbolt-2, Play should learn from it e.g. regarding the clean design separating Java from Scala instead of their confusing `play.x` vs `play.api.x`.

Comment: [ActionBuilders](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala/blob/master/code/app/be/objectify/deadbolt/scala/ActionBuilders.scala) provides a alternative syntax for [DeadboltActions](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala/blob/master/code/app/be/objectify/deadbolt/scala/DeadboltActions.scala) so `actionBuilder.WithAuthRequestAction()()` isn't valid.  See https://deadbolt-scala.readme.io/docs/action-builders and https://deadbolt-scala.readme.io/docs/action-composition for further details.